# How to limit the input of form control in Angular

Tags: angular, forms

I got a form using `FormGroup` & `FormControl` and in 1 field of input I want to limit the user to enter only numbers and it must be 5 digits. I know how to use `FormControl` validators but I don't need to validate. I want that the user won't be able to enter something wrong.
I want the user to see '00000' and let say the input was 6 so the user will see '00006' and if after that the input was 9 the user will see '00069'
and so on. The same process with erase number

**login.compenent.ts:**

```
loginForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
...
code: new FormControl('00000', Validators.compose(
   [ Validators.maxLengh(5), Validators.minLength(5),Validators.pattern('[0-9]{5}')]
)),
});
...
```

**login.component.html:**

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input type="" matInput placehodler="code" formControlName="code">
<mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the only-numberic input:

```html
<input type="number">
```

But if you want to use leading zero-s, then **you cannot use** this.

So because of this and your other problems, you need to use a simple text input, and write a custom logic on handling the user inputs in it. 
I suggest you use the [keyup event](https://angular.io/guide/user-input). You can get the current value of your input and always reshape it the way you want.

Something like this:

```
<input (keyup)="keyupHandler($event) [(ngModel)]="myVal">
...
keyupHandler(event: any){
  // modify directly myVal here, or
  // event.target.value contains the last user input's result 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In this case can use Directive

[Have a look on this sample on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/directive-to-formatnumbers)

```
<input type="text" formatNumber  >
```

```html
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core'

@Directive({
  selector: '[formatNumber]'
})
export class FormatNumberDirective {
  stringLength = 5;
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }


  @HostListener("keyup") onkeydown() {

    let value = this.el.nativeElement.value;
    value = value.split('0').join('');
    if (value.length > 5) {
      this.el.nativeElement.value = this.el.nativeElement.value.substr(0, 5);
      return;
    }

    this.el.nativeElement.value = this.padstring(value, "0", 5)

  }

  padstring(str, padString, length) {
    while (str.length < length)
      str = padString + str;
    return str;
  }
}
```

Hope this might help

Answer (score 1):

Use HTML Validator Simple and Easy.

```
<input type="text" name="usrname" maxlength="10">
```